# Pushdown automaton for language with "or"

Tags: pushdown-automata

> Find a pushdown automaton accepting the language $$L=\{A^i B^j C^k \mid 2k \le i \le 3k \text{ or } j \neq i+k \}.$$

I can't construct the automaton because I can only imagine it with multiple stacks or with set-theoretic intersections.

Comment: I got a solution on stackowerflow, but thanks for trying to help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47288671/find-the-pushdown-automata-of-this-language-l-ai-bj-ck-2k-i-3k-or-j#comment81527789_47288671

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you are able to construct PDAs for the following languages:
$$
\{ A^i B^j C^k : 2k \leq i \leq 3k \}, \\
\{ A^i B^j C^k : j < i+k \}, \\
\{ A^i B^j C^k : j > i+k \}. \\
$$
Now you can use non-determinism to construct a PDA which non-deterministically chooses which of the three PDAs to apply.